# How can I join multiple regex matches into one array element using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, arrays, join

Following is the script for matching regex and storing value in array:

```
    sub b1 {
    #   print $_;
        my @file = @_;
        my @value;
        my $find = qr/(\s+)([0-9]+)\s([A-Z])\s[0-1].[0-9]+\s->\s([A-Z])\s/;
        foreach my $file(@file){
            push (@value, $file=~ /$find/) ;
            print "\n";
        }
        return @value;
    }

    my @array_b1 = b1(@body);
    print "@array_b1 \n";

__DATA__

      28 C 0.510 -> L 0.923
      30 S 0.638 -> A 0.527
      31 A 0.496 -> P 0.952

__OUTPUT__

28 C L            30 S A            31 A P
```

While capturing values from regex and storing it an array, the script stores values in consecutive elements in array i.e. the above array has elements:

```
@array[1]=28
@array[2]=C
@array[3]=L
@array[4]=30.
```

Instead, I want to store values captured by the regex in same array element.  That is:

```
@array[1]=28CL
@array[2]=30SA
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: In Perl5, array elements use $, not @:  $array[1], $array[2], etc.  There are some places you can say @array[1] instead without it breaking, but not everywhere (which is why @array[1] will give you a warning - you do have warnings turned on, yes?)

Comment: Have you considered buying a book? http://books.perl.org/category/7

Comment: @sinan unur: I already have a book. thank for suggestion. do u know why the regex is matching and capturing information and placing them as consecutive elements?

Comment: @shubster because that's what m/// in list context does: It returns the matches as a list. Therefore, if you want all the matches concatenated into a string, you have to do it yourself using join as ysth answer shows. The match operator is explained in perldoc perlop as well as perldoc perlretut (see "Extracting Matches").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
push( @value, join( '', $file =~ /$find/ ) );
```